# In Meteor, simple Collection.find().fetch() is returning an empty array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

here is my code. Could anyone please help me out in knowing why the value of rekt on the runtime is an empty array? On my meteor all find().fetch() are returning an empty array only. Does anyone have any experience with this sort of a thing.

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');
rekt = PlayersList.find().fetch();
console.log(rekt);

ids = new Object();
sorted = new Object();
oldq = new Object;
try
{
rs1 = {name : "Sam"};
PlayersList.update(rs1 , {$set: {name : "Sam" , score : 100}} , {upsert:true});

console.log(resultset);
}catch(e)
{}

function selectscore(cutoff)
{
  var oldq = PlayersList.find().fetch();
  for(var a in oldq)
  {
    elm = oldq[a];
    if(elm.score<=cutoff)
    {
    sorted[elm.name] = elm.score;      
    }

  }    
 return sorted;
 }

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  oldq = PlayersList.find().fetch();

  for(var a in oldq)
  {
    elm = oldq[a];
    ids[elm.name] = elm._id;
  }
  selectscore(50);


  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get('counter');


    }

  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    PlayersList.update({name:"Bob"} , {$set:{name: "Mob", score: 500}});
    PlayersList.update({name:"Mob"} , {$set:{name: "Cobb", score: 5000}});
    resultset  = PlayersList.find().fetch();
    //console.log(resultset.attr(_id));
    rs = {name : "Slobb"};
    PlayersList.update({name:"Cobb"} , {$set:{name: "Slobb", score: 50000}});
    PlayersList.update( rs, {$set:{name: "Bob", score: 50}});
    newq = PlayersList.find().fetch();

  });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there publish/subscribe code?  https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe

Comment: no there isn't. I am a huge noob as far as Meteor is concerned. The autopublish and insecure are still on and the page used to load much before the collection data was loaded which used to cause a lot of problems here

Answer (score 0):

You are logging the same result twice. The array returned by `fetch` isn't reactive. Meaning, when you `fetch` and then insert, the array wont change. So try replacing the second `console.log(resultset);` with `PlayersList.find().fetch();`. Also, set up the proper publish/subscribe functions, (as @Paul described).

Answer (score 0):

it appears that there is some issue here not allowing the find().fetch() functions to return the object array. I tried kriegs solution but it did not work as well. I finally managed to solve the problem using Deps.autorun.

Thanks all

Comment: Deps? I'm afraid whatever solution you are following is highly outdated. `Deps` was renamed `Tracker` a while ago.